# Split two columns in one row

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table with two columns: Salary and Department_id

```
|Salary|Department_id|
|---------------------
|1000  |10           |
|2000  |90           |
|3000  |10           |
|4000  |90           |
```

Now I need to split this colums in one row and calculate sum of salary for every department.

Output:

```
|Dep10|Dep90|
|-----------|
|4000 |6000 |
```

NOTE: "Dep10" and "Dep90" are aliases.

I try to use decode or case

```
SELECT DECODE(department_id, 10, SUM(salary),NULL) AS "Dep10",
DECODE(department_id, 90, SUM(salary), NULL) AS "Dep90"
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
```

but I obtain this:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

```sql
select
    sum(case when Department_id = '10' then Salary end) as Dep10,
    sum(case when Department_id = '90' then Salary end) as Dep90
from employees
```

Comment: demo link : [Oracle 11g Release 2 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=93eea0102fbed1b37ad584520587c216)

Comment: Can help with example using subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Use `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( Salary, Department_id ) AS
SELECT 1000, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2000, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3000, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4000, 90 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
PIVOT  ( SUM( salary ) FOR Department_id IN ( 10 AS Dep10, 90 AS Dep90 ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DEP10 | DEP90
> ----: | ----:
>  4000 |  6000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=564fde0a1cd8cc32089714361ce7d05d)*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should:

1 - use GROUP BY clause on your first table.

2 - use PIVOT feature [you can learn about it here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html). In a few words, you can transpose columns and rows using it.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @bonex, you have a typo in your link it is "you can learn about it here"